# Problem with loading dynamic components: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: webpack, svelte

Context: We're rewriting a (very)large react UI in Svelte. In one section of the app are a number of plugins. Each plugin is a Component. Each plugin(component) is registered in an array. Each component in that array is dynamically imported, and dynamically displayed.

Store:

1. We create an array: `mycomponentsArray [ key, component_friendly_name, component_file_location, component-object (initially null)`.
2. Next we loop through the array, and load components from the array element file(`component_file_location`) into the array element object (`component_object`).
3. In the parent component we import the store.
4. Then we use an `[#each]` loop to load the components via <svelte:component > passing parameters.

As far as I know this is the correct model for creating application plugins.

5. But this approach generates the webpack critical error: `"Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"`

I've done a thorough search for solutions, and while I at least understand the problem facing webpack, I have four questions:

Question 1:  is there a webpack setting or plugin that will allow me to circumvent this error?

Question 2:  is there some reason I should NOT circumvent the error (other than it causes webpack to create a bigger file)

Question 3:  is there some obvious hack I can add to the js or svelte code to get around this issue?

Question 4:  Am I asking too much of the svelte tech, and I should just hard code the loading of the components into constants and limit dynamic components to dynamic rendering (looping through the array to display component names).

Thanks

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a GH repo? It would be easier to track the error.